# When change content of tab, how to dispose the old content automatically

Tags: wpf, silverlight, tabcontrol, tabitem

Example :

```
view = new viewOld();
view.Datacontext = new viewModelOld();
tabItem.Content = viewOld;
```

Now I want to dispose the old content when i change new content for tab :

```
tabItem.Content = viewNew;
```

How can i dispose the viewModelOld automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TabItem will not hold a reference to your old view, and if you are not holding any other references to it then the `GarbageCollector` of the framework will remove your old view from memory.

If your view implements `IDisposable` then you have to call its `Dispose` method explicitly, see [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your knowledge!!!I'm use Process Monitor to test Memory and when I change from heavy content to light content  the memory still increase!!!

Comment: As Martin says "if you are not holding any other references to it", so double check that your old VM isn't being referenced from elsewhere. Also GC doesn't take place as soon as you change that VM, so don't expect to see an instant reduction in memory just because you switched VMs. You can force an instant GC if you want though.

Comment: @Thinh: It may still increase, the GarbageCollector runs on its own schedule. Your part is done as soon as you released all references to it (and called Dispose on a IDisposable).